# How to reset files due to bad conflict?

Tags: git

I had bunch of changed files on my local disk (not committed yet!)
I wanted to pull and rebase the remote changes but something went wrong
when I did:
`git pull --rebase`

I believe there were conflicts and now several files on my project are old (which means I did something during the conflict that got it to use the server changes while I wanted to merge them with my local changes).

How can i revert everything so I can see my local changes before doing `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: to avoid this situation in the future, be sure to `git stash` your current uncommited changes before doing anything to repos... that way you can very quickly and reliably bring everything back.

Comment: Also, consider using `fetch` instead of `pull` so you can preview the changes (and conflicts!) by comparing, e.g., `master` and `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I just want to answer my own question since I managed to retrieve everything :)

I simply did `git reflog` and got the hash of *one commit before the rebase*.
Fortunately, git did a new commit before the pull so I could revert to that commit.

Then I did `git reset --hard <hash>`which brought all my changes before the pull.
Then I did pull again and merged correctly with whatever was on the server.